# keyboard macro for opening a file

Tags: keyboard-macros

How can I create a keyboard macro where a file `myfile` is opened by executing `M-x openmyfile`. The main part should look like

```
(fset 'openmyfile
   [?\C-x ?\C-f <dir of myfile> return])
```

but I don't want to enter the whole dir to myfile by writing every single char using `?/ ?d ?i ?r ...` and so on. How to insert the dir string into the macro definition?

Comment: What don't you just do a defun? challenge? ;-)

Comment: I think `(string-to-vector (kbd "C-x C-f /path/to/you/thing <return>"))` would work. Or, simpler `(read-kbd-macro "C-x C-f /path/... <return>")`

Comment: Don't do that. Use `(defun openmyfile () "Your doc string comes here." (interactive) (find-file "<path of myfile>"))` instead.

Comment: @JeanPierre unfortunately it’s only my close-to-zero knowledge about elisp ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by @Tobias in the comments, you can create a command to open your file:

```
(defun open-my-file () 
   (interactive)
   (find-file "/path/to/my/file"))
```

Then you can call it using `M-x` or binding to some key, like this:

```
(define-key global-map (kbd "C-c C-f") 'open-my-file)
```

But don't be afraid of messing with elisp, it's pretty easy because you don't actually need understand it too much to do some fun stuff.